# How to factorise $x^6 + 1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

How do I factorise this? I already said that

$$x^6 + 1 = 0 \implies (x^3)^2 + 1 = 0$$

so we then get

$$(x^3)^2 = - 1$$

and then there are no real roots. Similar thing happens if I try it as $(x^2)^3$.

How would I then go about factorising this? I know its possible as

$$(x^6 + 1) = (x^2 + 1)(x^4 - x^2 + 1).$$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3099663/589

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're on the right track with the $(x^3)^2$, ... thing. Use $(x^2)^3$ -- interpret it as a polynomial in $x^2$ (which will be cubic), as opposed to one in $x$. That is, write it as $u^3 + 1$ with $u = x^2$. Now factor that.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $  By the Factor Theorem  $\rm\ z-c\mid z^3 - c^3.\ $ Let $\rm\ z = x^2,\,\ c = -1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$(x^2+1)(x^2+\sqrt{3}x+1)(x^2-\sqrt{3}x+1)$$

**Edit:** I'm assuming that the questioner is seeking a factorization into irreducible polynomials with real coefficients.

Comment: This is a very terse response to a Question that has been around for more than six years.  Indeed the Question has an Accepted Answer, so you should articulate what you are adding in the way of new information.  A key aspect is what kind of coefficients are allowed in the (polynomial) factors.

Answer (score 0):

If $x^6+1=0$, then $x^3$ must be either $i$ or $-i$ (because $(x^3)^2=x^6=-1$). Hence, one must find the cube roots of $\pm i$. The numbers $i$ and $-i$ are easily seen to be cube roots of each other.

Now, $(a+bi)^3=a^3+3a^2bi+3a(bi)^2+(bi)^3=a^3+3a^2bi+3ab^2i^2+b^3i^3=a^3+3a^2bi-3ab^2-b^3i=(a^3-3ab^2)+(3a^2b-b^3)i$. If this were to equal $i$, then the real part $a^3-3ab^2$ would have to be zero. Hence, either $a=0$ or $a^2-3b^2=0$. If $a=0$, then one gets the solution $-i$. For the other two solutions, substitute $a=\pm b\sqrt{3}$ into the equation $3a^2b-b^3=1$ to get $3(3b^2)b-b^3=1$. Simplifying the left side, one gets $8b^3=1$. The only real solution for $8b^3=1$ is $b=\frac{1}{2}$.

Hence, the other two cube roots of $i$ (besides $-i$) are $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}+\frac{1}{2}i$ and $-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}+\frac{1}{2}i$. Conjugating those two cube roots of $i$, one gets $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}-\frac{1}{2}i$ and $-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}-\frac{1}{2}i$ as the two cube roots of $-i$ besides $i$.

The fully factorized form of $x^6+1$ (over the complex numbers) is therefore $(x-i)(x+i)(x-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}-\frac{1}{2}i)(x+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}-\frac{1}{2}i)(x-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}+\frac{1}{2}i)(x+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}+\frac{1}{2}i)$.