# Factorise $x^n + 1$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

Is there a way to factorise $x^n + 1$

I thought of doing it like this: $$x^n +1 = (x+1)(x^{n-1} - x^{n-2} + \cdots - x + 1)$$ but can't seem to get anywhere using this method.

Comment: See [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) for some ideas. It's mostly about $x^m-1$ and not $x^n + 1$, but they are closely related. Especially if $m = 2n$.

Comment: Chiming in with Arthur. Over $\Bbb{Q}$ the irreducible factors are those cyclotomic polynomials $\Phi_{d}(x)$ where $d\mid 2n$ but $d\nmid n$.

Comment: If $n$ is odd then $x + 1$ is a factor, if not then sometimes it doesn't like $x^2 + 1$, and sometimes it does, $x^2 + 1 | x^9 + 1$

Answer (score 3):

Write
$$
x^n+1 = \frac{x^{2n}-1}{x^n-1}
$$
The factorization over $\mathbb Q$ of the polynomials in the fraction are given by [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial).

Comment: There is no need to complicate things by doubling the degree.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I wouldn't think it complicates much. It is _exactly_ what is needed to be able to directly apply the cyclotomic polynomials from their wikipedia definition.

Comment: @Arthur: I don't see a significant benefit.

Comment: @YvesDaoust That's because you're good at math. There is no _mathematical_ benefit. But i think it's a decent thing if you're trying to help people who struggle to factor $x^n + 1$. It seems like it might be helpful to be given the wikipedia article on the factorisation of $x^{2n}-1$ and $x^n-1$, as there is none dedicated to $x^n + 1$. Of course, the _real_ judge of whether this is actually helpful is the OP.

Comment: @Arthur: sorry to contradict again. It takes mathematical culture to know about the cyclotomic polynomials, plus skills to transform the initial polynomial. Actually, an ad-hoc rabbit pulled from a hat. And a wasted opportunity to relate the factorization of the polynomial to its roots.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You're right that roots are nice too. But what if the person has never heard of complex numbers? Then roots won't help at all. However, factoring $x^m-1$ for higher and higher $m$, and noting which factors appear and how they relate to the factors of $m$ can be done entirely without complex roots. I think cyclotomic polynomials assumes fewer prerequisites than complex roots of unity: To someone who knows about factoring of polynomials, I can teach enough about cyclotomic polynomials to solve this problem much faster than I can teach enough about complex numbers.

Comment: @Arthur: are you serious ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Quite. I agree that in general, complex numbers is a _much_ more useful thing to know about than cyclotomic polynomials. It's a whole theory, after all, and not just a simple tool with some very specific niche uses. And if complex numbers is already known, then your approach is more elegant and enlightening. But in the context of this specific problem, assuming only the knowledge that the OP has explicitly demonstrated, I think this approach is closer to the one I would expect a student to take, and it's the one I would guide them towards if the goal was to just solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Factorization amounts to root finding.

$$x^n=-1\iff x=e^{i(2k+1)\pi/n}$$ and the factors are

$$x-e^{i(2k+1)\pi/n}$$ for $k=0,\cdots n-1$ (modulo $n$).

If you want a factorization with real coefficients only, then consider the roots in conjugate pairs.

$$(x-e^{i(2k+1)\pi/n})(x-e^{-i(2k+1)\pi/n})=x^2-2\cos\left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{n}\right)x+1.$$

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is even then the graph of $y=x^n+1$ is always above the $x$ axis so $x^n+1=0$ has no real roots.

If $n$ is odd then the graph of $y=x^n+1$ crosses the $x$ axis at $x=-1$ and cannot cross the $x$ axis anywhere else because $x^n+1$ is monotonically increasing. So $x^n+1=0$ has a single real root at $x=-1$, and so $x+1$ is a factor of $x^n+1$. In fact, for odd $n$:

$x^n+1=(x+1)(x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}+x^{n-3}-x^{n-4}+\dots-x+1)$

Comment: This looks exactly like what the OP has already done (except you've specified that it only works in odd degrees). I don't see how anything here will help the OP factorise their polynomial _further_.