# Why can we not factor $x^4+y^4$ or $x^6 + y^6$ using the patterns we find for the expressions $x^5+y^5$, $x^7+x^7$ and, $x^{2n+1} + x^{2n+1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, solution-verification, factoring

(a) The expression $x^5 + y^5$ can be written as the product of $x+y$ and another factor. Find that other factor.

$x^5 - y^5 = (x-y)(x^4+x^3y+x^2y^2+xy^3+y^4)$.

We can use this established result for $x^5 + y^5$

$x^5 + y^5 = x^5 - (-y)^5 = [(x-(-y)][x^4+x^3(-y)+x^2(-y)^2+x(-y)^3+(-y)^4]=(x+y)(x^4-x^3y+x^2y^2-xy^3+y^4)$.

(b) The expression $x^7 + y^7$ can be written as the product $x+y$ and another factor. Find that other factor.

$x^7 - y^7 = (x-y)(x^6+x^5y+x^4y^2+x^3y^3+x^2y^4+xy^5+y^6)$.

Once again using the established result we find,
$x^7 + y^7 = (x+y)(x^6-x^5y+x^4y^2-x^3y^3+x^2y^4-xy^5+y^6)$.

(c) Write $x^{2n+1} + x^{2n+1}$ as the product of two factors.

\begin{align*}
{x^{2n+1} + x^{2n+1}}&=(x+y)(x^{2n}+x^{2n-1}(-y)+\cdots + x(-y)^{2n-1}+(-y)^{2n})\\
&\,\,{=(x+y)\sum_{k=0}^{2n} x^{2n-k}(-y)^k}
\end{align*}

(d) Why does the factorization in the previous part fail when the powers of $x$ and $y$ are even? In other words, why can we not factor $x^4+y^4$ or $x^6 + y^6$ using the patterns we found in the first three parts?

$x^4 - y^4 = (x-y)(x^3+x^2y+xy^2+y^3)$

$x^6 - y^6 = (x-y)(x^5+x^4y+x^3y^2+x^2y^3+xy^4+y^5)$

When the powers are even, the factorization takes on a different form where the numbers of terms are even instead of odd as seen the earlier parts. The highest degree is also even so we end up having $x^n-y^n$ when we try to factor in the same way.

I'm still trying to figure out the factorization of $x^4+y^4$ and $x^6 + y^6$.

Comment: In fact $,x^6+y^6$ is divisible by $x^2+y^2$ , but $x^4+y^4$ is irreducible , at least over $\mathbb Q[x][y]$

Comment: Ask [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+x%5E6%2By%5E6).

Comment: Write $x^n+y^n=y^n(z^n+1)=y^n(z^{2n}-1)/(z^n-1)$ with $z=x/y$. Then read about  [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial). See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3099663/factorise-xn-1

Comment: However, $x^4+4y^4$ can actually be factored.

Comment: Because $x^n+y^n \ne x^n-(-y)^n$ if $n$ is even.

Comment: Define "*factor*". Every polynomial does in fact factor in linear terms over $\,\mathbb C\,$, or linear and quadratic terms over $\,\mathbb R\,$. For example $\,z^4+1 = \left(z^2 + \sqrt{2} z + 1\right)\left(z^2 - \sqrt{2} z + 1\right)\,$, though the polynomial is irreducible over $\,\mathbb Q\,$.

Comment: If you could factor $x^4+y^4=(x+y)(\cdots)$, then you can factor $x^4+1=(x+1)(\cdots)$ by letting $y\to1$. But $-1$ is not a root of $x^4+1$, so it can't be done.

Comment: Note that you can write $x^4+y^4=x^4-(\omega y)^4$ where $\omega$ is a complex 8th root of unity. So $x^4+y^4=(x-\omega y)\left(x^3+\omega x^2y+ixy^2+\omega i y^3\right)$.

Comment: @Peter More generally, $x^n+y^n$ is irreducible if and only if $n$ is a power of $2$.